# Matlab GUI button that toggles another button

Tags: matlab, user-interface, button, toggle, matlab-guide

Is there a way to create two toggle buttons in a Matlab GUI such that one toggles the other? In other words, if button A is on, how can I create a button B that when turned on makes A go off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have version R2009a, so I don't know if this works for you or not:

I defined two push buttons with `guide` (with default names). When the first is clicked it is disabled (Enable: Off), its Value set to 1 and its String to On; the second push button is set to the other state.  A similar behavior is given to the other button.

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
set(handles.pushbutton1,'Value',1,'String','On','Enable','Off')
set(handles.pushbutton2,'Value',0,'String','Off','Enable','On')
get(handles.pushbutton1)

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
set(handles.pushbutton1,'Value',0,'String','Off','Enable','On')
set(handles.pushbutton2,'Value',1,'String','On','Enable','Off')
```

If you want to *toggle the behavior* of button2 according to the state of button1 then do the following:

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

% this toggles button1 between 0 and 1 and its label between 'On' and 'Off'
p = 1-get(handles.pushbutton1,'Value');   
set(handles.pushbutton1,'Value',p)
if p==0
    set(handles.pushbutton1,'String','Off')
else
    set(handles.pushbutton1,'String','On')
end



% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

% Behavior of button2 is dependent on state of button1
p = get(handles.pushbutton1,'Value');

if p==0
    % Do this when button1 has its label to 'Off' (and Value to 0)
else
    % This will execute when button1 has a Value of 1 (and its label showing 'On')
end
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: That does the job, thank you. However, in my case I have a command (specifically a delete video object) when I toggle my button 1 to OFF. If I use your code, pressing the button 2 simply toggles the button 1 OFF without executing the delete video object command. Any suggestion?

Comment: The 'Off' and 'On' on my code are just labels, you could change them to whatever you want.  I don't know your delete video command, but if you want to have that action happen when you push button 2 put the command right after the last line.

Comment: Mm not really. I just realised that I don't think what I want it's possible to do. Ideally I would like to execute part of the code that is in button 1 BEFORE the code of button 2 is executed, even though I have pressed button 2.

Comment: Since you are pressing button2, you could copy the code in button1 into button2 and only execute it if button1 state is in a certain state (inside an if..end), and then execute the code in button2.  But all this code should be inside button2.

Comment: I wanted to avoid that but apparently that's the only solution. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is my code:

```
function button1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
if get(hObject,'Value')==1

    %do something here

else

    %do something else (in my case delete a video object)
```

If I now put a second button and use the command

```
set(handles.button1,'Value',0)
```

The result is that my first button toggles but the command after the `else` is not executed.
Is there a way to execute that command as well?